# Как сделать асинхронный цикл?

Tags: python, discord.py

Всем привет! Возможно я плохо ищу, потому что я не нашел конкретно того, что мне нужно. Буду благодарен, если кто-то скинет документацию. Я хотел сделать асинхронный цикл, который будет вечно спустя 10 секунд проверять наличие меньше 99 монет на балансе пользователя, но как сказал ранее - не знаю как. Вот кусочек кода, который нужно обернуть.

```
                await asyncio.sleep(10)
            if balance < 99:
                await ctx.author.remove_roles(rolecreate)
                await ctx.send(embed = timesup)
            else:
                cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash - 99 WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id))
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

обернули

```
def balancetask(ctx,cursor):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        if balance < 99:
            await ctx.author.remove_roles(rolecreate)
            await ctx.send(embed = timesup)
        else:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash - 99 WHERE id = {}".format(ctx.author.id))
```

и запускаем

```
 asyncio.get_running_loop().create_task(balancetask(ctx,cursor))
```

но курсор лучше получать новый на каждой итерации.

Comment: Спасибо, оно работает. Можете ещё немного помочь ? Я хотел при каждом запуске проверять всех пользователей на наличие роли. Если истинно, то будет запускаться асинхронный цикл, если нет, то просто пропуск. Я создал новую тему, если не сложно.